# #if to determine device type in .h xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, preprocessor, header-files

I am sure that this probably something extremely easy (or it can't be done), but I can't seem to find anything on it.

In one of my classes .h file I need to determine if the app is running on an iPad or an iPhone. Then change the value of the #define accordingly.

Ideally I would this it would look something like this:

```
#if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone

#define deltaX 10.0
#define theda  15.0
#define threshHold 267.0

#endif

#if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

#define deltaX 78.1
#define theda  67.2
#define threshHold 453.0

#endif
```

I am not sure what to use, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do this, as in a universal app the same code runs on iPhone as on iPad, so this decision must be made at run-time, not compile-time.

You should declare these variables in a header file, and then set them at run time depending on the value of `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`.

Comment: Dooah..I don't know why I didn't think about that. Of course preprocessor won't know the difference in the device. I should have known that :(

Answer (score 14):

A little late to the party, but figured I'd share what worked for me.

A solution that has been working for me is to define IS_IPAD and IS_IPHONE somewhere like so

```
#define IS_IPAD   (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Then when needing the other defines based on ipad/iphone, do something like this

```
#define deltaX (IS_IPAD? 78: 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You already have the code to determine the device, so that's fine.

I'd create your defines as follows:

```
#define padDeltaX 10.0
#define phoneDeltaX 78.1
... etc
```

Then in your class file:

```
if (if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    // do iPhone processing with the variables
}
else
{
    // must be iPad
}
```

Alternatively:

```
float variableOne, variableTwo; // etc

if (if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    variableOne = phoneDeltaX;
    variableTwo = phoneTheta; // etc
}
else
{
    // must be iPad
    variableOne = padDeltaX;
    variableTwo = padTheta; // etc
}

// now do the shared processing with variableOne, variableTwo etc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is was my second option, its just that my definitions are used quite a bit so I wanted to say as far away from using the if/else's in my .m.